# Unable to read file from encrypted s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I'm unable to read a file from encrypted s3 bucket in a lambda.

Below is my policy document where i'm giving access to s3 as well as kms. I've attached this policy to lambda.

When i try to read a file from the bucket, I get `Access Denied` error.

I'm adding `kms:RequestAlias` condition to kms statement so that the lambda will only have access to keys which has `mytoken` in the alias.

I suspect this is where i'm making mistake because if i remove the condition, the lambda gets access to all keys and read the encrypted file without any issues.

Can someone help me restrict access to only keys which has `mytoken` in the alias

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_s3_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket*",
      "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket*/*"
    ]
    actions = [
      "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
      "s3:CreateBucket",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
      "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]
  }


  statement {

    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "kms:RequestAlias"
      values   = [
        "alias/*mytoken*"
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This probably does not work because S3 does not encrypt with the aliased key but with the regular key id. The fact that there is an alias for that key somewhere does not and cannot matter. The request does not know anything about the potentially existing alias.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (I was trying to download the files from a couple of encrypted buckets directly from the AWS console and your case is in fact slightly different) was replacing *kms:RequestAlias* with *kms:ResourceAliases*.

```
statement {
  sid    = "AllowKMSAccessUsingAliases"
  effect = "Allow"

  actions = [
    "kms:Decrypt",
  ]

  resources = [
    "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:111111111111:key/*",
  ]

  condition {
    test     = "ForAnyValue:StringEquals"
    variable = "kms:ResourceAliases"
    values = [
      "alias/alias-bucket-1",
      "alias/alias-bucket-2",
    ]
  }
}
```

According to what the AWS documentation says, it makes sense at least for me: it seems that you should use *kms:RequestAlias* when you are including the alias as part of your KMS request like in the image below:

[image]

When you use *kms:ResourceAliases* what gets checked is the alias associated to the KMS resource involved in the operation regardless of whether the alias was explicitly included in the request or not

[image]

So probably, your lambda function, when asking for the un-encryption of a file in a bucket, is using the KMS id in the request instead of the KMS alias and if that is the case *kms:RequestAlias* won't work because there is no alias in the request to be checked.